# Convert JSON to RSS via Web API?

Tags: c#, json, rss, asp.net-web-api, httphandler

I would like to create a generic Web API action that will accept a JSON URL as a parameter, then convert it to RSS. Everywhere I look I find RSS to JSON but not the other way around.

I did not want to use a 3rd party service but instead looking for a library that can do this. Any idea on how to leverage Web API to do this or should I just create a simple HTTP Handler for this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say a JSON URL? 

Also, do you understand the difference between HTTP Handlers and Web API (not trying to be patronizing just trying to get a grasp for where to begin to answer your question)?

Comment: I have a URL that already services JSON. Some properties are assumed like title, content, published date, etc. So I would like to consume that in an Web API controller and return RSS (via parsing, mapping, etc). Instead of the overkill of creating a custom media format (unless RSS is built into web api), I thought maybe an HTTP Handler would be easier since I can return raw data which would be an RSS / XML. I was hoping for a library to do the heavy lifting of creating the RSS format though too.

Comment: OK, well I can't tell you anymore than you already know then :) As far as I know Web API doesn't support RSS/XML content type out of the box. Also, I've never heard of a JSON to RSS library. Not to say it isn't out there but I'd be Googling for it just like you.

Comment: @TruMan1 - what did you wind up doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implementing your own RSS or Atom custom `MediaTypeFormatter`.  You can implement it so that the request will use this formatter when the accept header is set to `application/atom+xml` or `application/rss+xml`.

Filip has a blog describing this:
[RSS & Atom MediaTypeFormatter for ASP.NET WebAPI](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/04/rss-atom-mediatypeformatter-for-asp-net-webapi)

Answer (score -2):

[Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) provide a feed API which does [RSS to JSON conversion](http://blog.superfeedr.com/convert-rss-to-json/) both when you poll feeds and when you want to be notified for changes in them.

Comment: that is the exact opposite of what OP requested